# Как получить данные из DataGrid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Как получить все данные из DataGrid. А так же как удалить строку

Необходимо после изменения строки, получить либо номер строки и изменения, либо все строки. Для того чтобы изменить данные из БД(простой txt файл)

разметка DataGrid

```
<DataGrid x:Name="LVVid" Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellEditEnding="LVVid_CellEditEnding">
        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="DataGridRow_MouseDoubleClick"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ФИО" Binding="{Binding FIO}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Курс, направление" Binding="{Binding Kurs}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Место" Binding="{Binding Mesto}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Вид практики" Binding="{Binding Vid}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Начало" Binding="{Binding Nachalo}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Конец" Binding="{Binding Konec}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Руководитель" Binding="{Binding Ruk}"/>

        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

обработка изменения

```
private void LVVid_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] str = new string[spisok.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < spisok.Length; i++)
        {
            Blank context = spisok[i];

            str[i] = spisok[i].FIO + ":" + spisok[i].Kurs + ":" + spisok[i].Mesto + ":" + spisok[i].Vid + ":" + spisok[i].Nachalo + ":" + spisok[i].Konec + ":" + spisok[i].Ruk;

        }
        File.Delete("База.txt");
        File.AppendAllLines("База.txt", str);
    }
```

Comment: Как данные добавляли, так и забирайте) 
Как вы грид биндите?

Comment: Используйте привязку к коллекции (через ItemsSource), в качестве коллекции используйте `ObservableCollection`, у нее есть событие `CollectionChanged`. Также ваши сущности в коллекции должны реализовать `INOtifyPropertyChanged`, тогда вы сможете получать уведомления об их изменениях.

Comment: при изменении ДатаГрида, меняется и привязанная структура данных?  Тобишь class с полями get set?

Comment: При изменении DataGrid структура данных в коде не меняется. При обработке изменения, и записи данных из списка, записывается тоже самое что и до изменения

Comment: http://prntscr.com/k3a9k5 вот скрин. Меняю указанное поле, на вывод указываю то же самое поле но не с DataGrid а из структуры которая указана в ItemsSource

Comment: Да меняется. Если сделать всё как я вам написал.

Comment: ок. Тогда вопрос. У меня уже реализовано всё на структуре с полями гет, сет. Как я могу перевести их из struct в ObservableCollection и обратно чтобы взять его поля

Comment: ObservableCollection - это коллекция. Просто сделайте коллекцию своих элементов: `ObservableCollection<Student>` и привяжите DataGrid к ней.

Comment: смотри. Сделал вот в таком порядке.

ObservableCollection<Blank> ar= new ObservableCollection<Blank>;
ar.Add(BlankPerem);
LVvid.ItemsSource=ar;
Изменил датагрид
ar[0].FIO показывает тоже самое что и до изменения

Comment: Неа, не верю. У меня всё работает. Что-то значит не так у вас. Перепроверяйте.

Comment: извините. Можно Ваш вк или какой либо другой источник для связи с вами?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79840/discussion-between--nop-and-lord).